# Exhaust fan and corresponding power switch in each of two bathrooms, with both fans being turned on simultaneously by actuating either switch

Tags: exhaust-fan

Each of two bathrooms in the Condo we just purchased, has a ceiling exhaust fan and corresponding control switch.  For some reason, changing the state of the fan in either bathroom, by changing its corresponding switch, simultaneously changes the fan in the other room to the same state. In other words, both fans are actuated on together (and off together) when ever either of the switches is actuated.

Comment: Welcome to the site Dan.  You forgot to ask a question.  You described a situation, but didn't say anything else.

Comment: Quality exhaust fans usually have a timer so they run for a tine after the light is turned off...

Comment: Is this definately two separate fans, or one shared fan and two duct inlets?

Comment: Are the two bathrooms on the same circuit?

Comment: Sounds like you have 2 fans connected together with a pair of 3-way switches controlling them. Strange...

Comment: Normally each fan would be controlled by its own single pole switch. If it is a standard toggle switch, it will have the words "ON" and "OFF" on the toggle. But a 3-way switch has nothing written on the toggle. Which do you have?